# Is my pi4 dead and How to determine what exactly happened?

Tags: pi-4, hardware, rip

Apparently, I somehow bricked my new pi4.

When I plug it in, the red (power) LED is working, but the green one (boot) is not.
To be exact: when everything, including the SD card is taken out the pi, the green LED should blink 4 times.
However, with or without SD-card, the green LED just blinks once when plugged, and never blinks again until restart.

So, I guess my pi is dead.

**My question is more of a technical curiosity: is there a way to somehow determine, which exact part of pi is dead? What tools are needed for that?**

*Side question: any suggestions, if it might be alive still?..*

Comment: Did it ever work? Do you get anything on screen when powered on without sd card? Have you tried another freshly flashed sd card with the latest Raspberry Pi OS? What power supply?

Comment: if you've kept it up to date, it may boot from a USb drive